# Missing Template - Template is Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, devise

I should preface by acknowledging I am very new to rails. Though I've had a successful track record with Rails in the past, I am getting an error I cannot get by. This is the following error:

*Missing template /ctoneposts with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.*

The odd thing is, I was able to use the form_for to create posts until my code stopped working. I have two posts I was able to add dynamically in my app on the web. Following this, I added devise gem and began the process of assigning Users to posts (everything was fine until I went in for a test!)

This is my controller:

```
    class CtonepostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @ctoneposts = Ctonepost.all
      @ctoneposts = Ctonepost.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def create
      post_params = params.require(:ctonepost).permit(:content)

      @ctonepost = Ctonepost.new(content: post_params[:content])

      if @ctonepost.save
          redirect_to ctoneposts_path
      else 
          render ctoneposts_path
      end
  end 

end
```

I am getting the error around the render ctoneposts_path.

This is my index.html.erb file:

```
<%= render "ctoneform" %>
<br>

<%= render @ctoneposts %>
```

_ctonepost.html.erb:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <p><%= ctonepost.content %></p>
    <small><%= ctonepost.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></small>
</div>
```

My view is partial. I did some changing around (I don't remember what I did) and it eventually spit out a partial view error.I even went so far in changing what the files were saved as, etc, and nothing seems to be working and it is driving me crazy! Please help a new Ruby on Rails coder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I can see here. First, you don't `render` a path. You render a template. So calling `render` and then calling a path is not going to work.

If you want to go back to index or any other path, you can

```
redirect_to some_path
```

Or maybe you just need to render the 'new' template again (which maybe includes the form):

```
render :new
```

Comment: I ultimately would want it to redirect to the "ctoneposts_path" because the dynamic form is on that page and the posts appear on that page. If I do "else redirect_to ctoneposts_path" no error comes up but the post does not show. Obviously it makes no sense since it is the "if" statement.

Comment: Try render :index then.

Comment: :index creates an ArgumentError in Ctoneposts#create. I may just scrap the application and start over without partial views. I haven't always done it this way so I'm unfamiliar.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however. I will keep what you said in mind for my future development. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are rendering a partial within a template you can use,

```
<%= render partial: 'ctoneposts/ctonepost' %>
```